# HTML. Download shortcut to PHP / HTML

Tags: php, css, html

How to create download button to download link / shortcut to website?

I mean after clicking download button It should download `example.html`. After opening `example.html` It should open / redirect to `www.mysite.com/etc/index.php?Id=127`. Is It possible at all?

Something like: `<a href="index.php?Id=127" download>`, but It will download PHP file, what is wrong. It should download HTML with redirect to PHP.

Comment: Please detail the user experience. I visit your site, click on a button, gets prompted to save a file and then gets redirected?

Comment: After clicking download button, It should download file `example.html`. After opening that file It should open browser with url `www.mysite.com/etc/index.php?Id=127`

Comment: So you want a script in example.html redirect? `<script>location.replace("http://www.example.com/etc/index.php");</script>` - if you want example.html to stay in history, use `location="http://...."` instead

Comment: The question is unclear. Also you cannot redirect after a download has finished, you may be able to redirect after a download has started, but that requires javascript.